# How can I tell Windows Mail to send a message to mail server saying "mail read"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, windows-phone-8

My company gave me a POP3 e - mail account.

I have added it to my desktop computer from Windows Mail and also I have a WP8 cell phone.

Even though I read my e - mail from my computer, when I sync my WP8 again with the mail server, it still seems unread in my phone. ( or vica - verse )

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POP3 is a one-directional protocol, in that once you download mail, it resides on your POP3 mail client, and has no further communication with the server until the next time you poll for new mail.

This article elaborates: http://mail2web.com/blog/2010/02/pop-imap-difference/

Some mail servers block the POP3 'delete' function and retain a copy on the server, but unlike IMAP, there is no client/server relationship.

Your best option is to re-create your mail profile using IMAP (or Exchange ActiveSync if it's an Exchange/Outlook.com server) so that your client can bi-directionally communicate with the server.

Comment: What do you mean create your mail profile using IMAP? Is it something I choose? Because I think they gave me some settings like this ( I cant really remember it was some time ago )

Comment: Does your company use it's own hosted mail (on a server somewhere)? Or do they use a webmail service like gmail, outlook.com, or Office 365?

Comment: They use their own server.

Comment: Then in that case, I'd recommend contacting your company's technical support and asking if they offer a different protocol like IMAP or ActiveSync. There simply isn't any other way of getting that to work with POP3.

Comment: Thanks, what a shame. I will read every e - mail twice then.

Comment: Yeah - POP3 is the most frustrating protocol ever, but since it's a 1/4 century old protocol, I guess we can't expect too much.